# Prove the following polynomial equation has no answers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Assume there two polynomials for which the following equation$$P(Q(x))=Q(P(x))$$holds for $x\in\Bbb R$. Also the equation $P(x)=Q(x)$ has no real root. Prove that the following equation$$P(P(x))=Q(Q(x))$$has no real roots either.

Sorry for having no idea with this! Do you have any? Please subscribe...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $P(x) = Q(x)$ has no real root, one of $P,Q$ must be strictly greater than the other, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Without loss of generality, assume $P$ is the greater one.

Then for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$P(P(x)) > Q(P(x)) = P(Q(x)) > Q(Q(x))$$

Comment: Very cute!.....

Comment: NIce. Final paren missing.

Comment: @marty cohen: Thanks, fixed.